# ratio of the number of saddle points to local minima

Tags: analysis, optimization, maxima-minima

As far as I know the problem with gradient descent algorithms for solving non-convex optimization problems is getting "stuck" in a local minima.

In the paper
[Identifying and attacking the saddle point problem in
high-dimensional non-convex optimization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2572v1.pdf)
they argue that the more profound difficulty originates from the
proliferation of saddle points, not local minima, especially in high dimensional problems of practical interest.

I am posting this here because my question is a mathematical one:

"Consider minimizing a randomly chosen error function of a
single scalar variable, given by a single draw of a Gaussian process. (Rasmussen and Williams,
2005) have shown that such a random error function would have many local minima and maxima,
with high probability over the choice of the function, but saddles would occur with negligible probability."

So far so good

**"On the other-hand, random Gaussian error functions over N scalar variables, or dimensions, are increasingly likely to have saddle points rather than local minima as N increases."**

**"The ratio of the number of saddle points to local minima increases
exponentially with the dimensionality N."**

Why?

Intuitively that makes sense to me, but how would you go about finding or calculating this ratio.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Mostly heuristics: Let $a$ be a critical point and write
$$ f(a+h)=f(a)+ f''(a)[h,h] + o(|h|^2)$$
Suppose (not obvious how to make this rigourous!) that
 $f''(a)$ is centered random gaussian (GOE(n)). Then the distribution function for
its eigenvalues is
$$ P(\lambda_1,...\lambda_n)= K \prod_{i<j} |\lambda_i-\lambda_j| 
\exp \left( -\frac{1}{4\sigma^2} \sum_k\lambda_k^2 \right) .$$
If not for the product of differences the formula suggests that
integrating only over $\lambda_k\geq 0$ should produce $(1/2)^n$ of total probability. I think the product difference tends to amplify this behavior (since positive 'squeezes' together eigenvalues) but I don't really know how to make all this rigourous.